# Format conditions with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to use VBA to create conditional formating for my table.
I have numbers in columns C and D. I need the conditional formating to compare if numbers in C column are bigger than in D column and that same row D column cell should not be blank. If this is the case that cell in C column will be colored red, but if either argument is false, no format conditions should be applied. Table is dynamic and changes it's size.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = "Projects" Then
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").Range("C" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Projects").rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            With ws.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C$2>$D$2 & $D$2<>"""
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
```

So far this gives me an error:
Invalid procedure call or argument. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: `"=$C$2>$D$2 & $D$2<>"""` is not valid. You are trying to concatenate 2 ranges with a `&` character?

Comment: Record a macro that does what you want it to do, and then look at what it puts for that argument.

Comment: You want `AND`, not `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Formula1` needs to be an Excel formula (not VBA) and the function for that is `AND`. Be careful that you don't put absolute references into your formula, so get rid of all the `$` in it. And you have to double all quotes so that VBA sends then to Excel.
Your formula is `=AND(C2>D2,D2<>"")` so put this line to your code:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(C2>D2,D2<>"""")"
```

Comment: i know it is not social network, but i just must say thank you. you gave me more information about this than i've got last days google'ing. i always tried using absolutes in my formulas.